# Why is my WD HDD making a curious sound?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, clicking-sound

I've tried to access an 3.0TB Hard-Drive from Western Digital (Model WD30EZRX).

The hard drive is not being shown by the operating system and it creates the following (repeating) sound:

https://vocaroo.com/1iDexouB3Sme

Could anyone tell me what that sound means?

Comment: You need to take this to a data recovery lab if you want the data.

Comment: @John You cant use/test it with some Software because, the hard-drive will not be detected by the system or some software. Hear the sound at the link, that beeptone the hard-drive will be created

Comment: @JoepvanSteen i dont want to recover any data, please read the question: what the sound says?

Comment: It says the drive is unusable. If you don't need data recovery bin it and get a new one.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Can you provide official resources as a source for your statement, or is this just your opinion?

Comment: It's hardly a matter of opinion that this does not sound like a healthy drive if you have worked with hard drives, even only healthy ones for more than 30 years. A healthy hard drive should not make mechanical noises like this one does. A smart-ass attitude isn't exactly what you'd expect towards people trying to answer your question.

Comment: FWIW, collection of sounds of 'sick' drives: https://www.northwind.gr/en/data-recovery/damaged-hard-drive-sounds

Comment: What does a smart-ass attitude have to do with wanting more information? There are also beep codes with tables for mainboards, which then lead to an error. Excuse me if I'm asking explicitly because I'm interested?

Comment: @AdrianPreuss No offense, but your question to ChanganAuto asking for "official resiurces" does come across as being argumentative.   We are not an official WD service center, but a bunch of people with a lot of experience with drives.   Yours does not sound normal.

Comment: These sounds have zero to do with beep codes that are purposely generated.

Comment: Adrian, you are expecting too much! If your disk is not recognized by your operating system the most likely assumption is that your disk sound suggests that it fails on an operation that is needed to be able to react on operating system requests. I guess it is trying to read firmware code from the rotating platters and fails repeatedly and gives up finally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That drive is poked.  From the sounds of it the drive it sounds to me like it is continually hitting the head against the "stop" on the outside of the drive (for the first 2 seconds), and it sounds like the drive is then trying to move back and do a reset.

The best I can offer up as "evidence" would be this [Seagate support document](https://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/kb/identifying-hard-drive-sounds-and-determining-what-they-mean/) which says "...if a hard clicking persists or is accompanied by any kind of repeating clunking (or grinding) sound, then there is likely a physical issue with the drive. When possible, compare to other drives known to be healthy. " - although that is for a WDSeagate, not WD drive - that said, the recording you have does appear to be picking up a lot of "digital" noise.

At about [4:20 in this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/mmQNAGQ5Pas?feature=shared&t=260) has a faulty WD drive which has some commonality with what you are hearing.